# Waiting XML parse process before calling another method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am parsing an **XML** web service and after that parse finishes I want to **call another method**. But my code calls the method during the parse process. What I want is to wait till the parse process end. Here is my code:

```
    ArsivNoCheck *arsivNoCheck = [ArsivNoCheck alloc];
    [arsivNoCheck checkArsivNo:_txtArsivNo.text];  //Here I call parsing method in another class

    //Here I call the method
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sampleMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    -(void) sampleMethod
    {
    //some code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/completionBlock), and its method `completionBlock`.

Then, you would be able to perform your parsing, and at the end of it, execute some code.

*Note : If you plan to update the UI, take care, because the `completionBlock` is not necessarily running on the main thread!*

---

From [NSOperation's Doc reference :](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/completionBlock)

> **completionBlock**
>
> Returns the block to execute when the operation’s main
>   task is complete.
>
> `-(void (^)(void))completionBlock`
>
> *Return Value*
>
> The block to execute after the operation’s main task is completed. This block takes no
>   parameters and has no return value.
>
> *Discussion*
>
> The completion block you provide is executed when the value
>   returned by the isFinished method changes to YES. Thus, this block is
>   executed by the operation object after the operation’s primary task is
>   finished or cancelled.

Example :

```
[filterOp setCompletionBlock: ^{
    NSLog(@"Finished filtering an image.");
}];
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) on Ray Wenderlich's site for implementation.